# Audio Not Playing in iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, avaudioplayer

My app opens perfectly in the simulator, but when I press my button to play, no sound plays. The button appears to be pressed, but no audio is played. Is the issue with my code, or the simulator?

Here's my ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

}

- (IBAction)Whaddup;
- (IBAction)Speak;
- (IBAction)Hail;

@end
```

and my ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController




- (IBAction)Whaddup {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Whaddup" ofType:@"wav"];
    AVAudioPlayer *theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    [theAudio play];
}

- (IBAction)Hail {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Hail" ofType:@"wav"];
    AVAudioPlayer *theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    [theAudio play];
}

- (IBAction)Speak {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Speak" ofType:@"wav"];
    AVAudioPlayer *theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    [theAudio play];
}




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Does anybody have an idea as to why this isn't working? I have my three buttons linked up with my First Responders, using the "Touch Up Inside" for each button.

Comment: Did you use breakpoints to make sure the methods are getting called?

Comment: Are the sounds copied to the app's bundle? You can check that in the 'Copy Bundle Resources' section of your target's build phases.

Comment: I recently updated to Xcode 14.1 and there was no audio in the simulators. The simulator has a small button to go into silent mode, like the real device. I turned the silent mode on, and then back off, and the sound came back. I hope this helps to people like me googling this in 2022...

Answer (score 0):

try to do the following :
you create a folder in your project called "Resources" and add you file music "test.mp3" for example:
and in .h file:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@property(retain,nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer * audioPlayer;// you add this variable
```

and in .m file

```
@synthesize audioPlayer;
-(void) readMP3{
    if (![audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],@"test.mp3"]];
        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
        [audioPlayer play];
    }
}
```

and

```
-(void) stopReading{
[audioPlayer stop];
}
```

i hope that help you

Comment: it work for me! have you add AVFoundation framework in your Build phases? and what types of errors? can you show me?

Comment: For the .h file I got the "A parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition" (this was for the @property)

Comment: The .m file gave me both "Property implementation must have its declaration in interface", and "Unknown receiver 'audioPlayer' did you mean 'AVAudioPlayer'". What might've happened?